# grep with pattern file returning all lines instead of targets

Tags: grep

I tried to use grep to sub-sample a file using a pattern list in a second file. However, whenever I run it, grep just returns everything that is in the first file.

```
 grep -A1 -w --file=Fmerg_U1_filtering.txt Fmerg_final.fasta
```

However, when I use this more cumbersome approach, it works perfectly fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read i; do
    grep -A1 -w $i Fmerg_final.fasta
done < Fmerg_U1_filtering.txt
```

Any ideas what could be the problem? This is driving me crazy!

```
head Fmerg_U1_filtering.txt
Transcript_25
Transcript_455
Transcript_526
Transcript_631
Transcript_631
```

Comment: Have you got a blank line in your `txt` file?

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very likely, the text in your `Fmerg_U1_filtering.txt` has trailing/leading spaces.

Assume there were trailing spaces, your grep command with `--file` will try to match those spaces as well, however, your shell script with `$i` (without quotes) will ignore the spaces.

So please check the file `Fmerg_U1_filtering.txt`, remove leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: or empty lines. Thanks, this answer helped a lot